# Adamic Adar coefficient for Link Prediction in R

Tags: r, for-loop, networking, scoring

Hey guys I'm trying to write an R function that computes a summation. Specifically program the following formula:
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBbDF.png)

This is what I have but i can't figure out why it won't work or what I am doing wrong. Note this function resembles the Adamic Adar scoring coefficient.

Please note that the original data is called "fblog" and has 192 vertices.

```
#Scoring function
library(sand)
nv <- vcount(fblog)
ncn2 <- numeric()
upgrade_graph(fblog)
A2 <- get.adjacency(fblog)
for(i in (1:(nv-1))){
 ni <- neighborhood(fblog, 1, i)
 nj <- neighborhood(fblog, 1, (i+1):nv)
 nbhd.ij <- mapply(intersect, ni, nj, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
 for(i in unlist(nbhd.ij)) {
    k_deg = unlist(lapply(nbhd.ij, length))
    temp = 1/(log(k_deg))
 }
 ncn2 <- c(ncn2, temp)
}
```

Comment: It's better to pre-allocate vectors when you know their length ahead of time. `ncn2 <- numeric()` should be `ncn2 <- numeric(nv-1)` I think. Also, `temp = 1/(log(k_deg))` is not referencing past instances of the inner `for` loop, it's just repeating the same value (as long as the undefined k_deg) is not changing.

Comment: Even when I do this I am not getting the correct matrix for ncn2 that follows the formula I posted. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you could use the `lengths` function to get k_deg: `k_deg = lengths(nbhd.ij)`. I'd suggest breaking the problem into as small parts as you can. Make sure each part works before putting it together. For example, if you know what the first value of ncn2 should be, then pull the stuff in the loop block out and inspect each line until it works.

Comment: Thanks! I might try and write my own similarity function to find the AA index for each set of vertices and then use a double for loop to call that function for each pair of vertices.

Comment: Marissa, take a look at the `similarity.invlogweighted` function that's available in the igraph package. The formula you linked matches the description of that function. The results from that function might be useful in evaluating if your function is giving the correct output.